# The Operation has time out at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, timeout

WebSevice TimeOut Occurred while performing a long running task for eg. Executing an Stored Procedure in Service call.

To Overcome I've tried setting the timeout value in web service proxy class

```
 WebReference.ProxyClass myProxy = new WebReference.ProxyClass();
 myProxy.Timeout = 999999999; //in milliseconds, i.e. 277 Hours
```

and modified the web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="999999" executionTimeout="99999999" />
```

But still the same Exception :

```
 The Operation has time out at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
```

any ideas ? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried altering settings in the IIS?

Comment: I've tried but can u name them.

Comment: In IIS Manager, right click on the site and go to Manage Web Site -> Advanced Settings. In there, under Connection Limits you should see Connection Time-out.

Comment: yes,Limit set to 65535

Comment: are you sure operation is not timing out at server side?

Comment: same at both server and client side.

Comment: i am having the same problem. can't find any solution on the web. Help!